# Custom PHP Forms Throwing Error (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to code a custom PHP form for my site for hours and tried multiple tutorials and followed different responses I've seen here, but nothing seems to be working and I'm not sure why.

I've simplified what I'm trying to do so that I can just get it to work, then build on top of it. So, I've built a little "example form" on my homepage.

**Form Goal:**

After form submit, reload the same page but display user-submitted input rather than the form.

**Work so far:**

1. My site homepage is set to a page called "Welcome". So, www.mysite.com shows the page titled "Welcome" in the WP Dashboard. On "Welcome" in the WP Dashboard, I set the template to "My Welcome Template".
2. In the template PHP file I have this code:

   ```
   <?php

   if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
       ?>
       Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>.
       <?php
   }
   else {
       ?><br>
       <form action="" method="post">
           <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn"></p>
       </form>
       <br><?php
   }  
   ?>
   ```

**Error:**

Upon submitting the form, the page refreshes. Although the URL still reads just "www.mysite.com", it seems to be loading a different template than the template on "Welcome". This seems to be the "hey, we didn't find that thing you looked for" template, and the text on the page reads like so.

> Oops! That page can’t be found.
>
> It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the links below or a search?
>
> Search
>
> Archives
>
> Try looking in the monthly archives.

Comment: ARGH ctrl K didn't work, working on editing to include PHP code.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: Good point - when I click submit it reloads the page, but displays a different page template (it seems like the "Error, page not found" template), though the url reads "www.mysite.com". The page says "Oops! That page can’t be found."

Comment: Updated to include exact issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if the $_POST array exist and a special value ist not empty, e.g.

```
    if( !empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['name']) ){
     // Your Welcome Part
     } else {
     // The form part
    }
```

Comment: `empty()` checks if something is set and if it's not null.  no need for both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different name for text element.

example:

```
<?php    
if (isset($_POST["full_name"])) {
        ?>
        Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["full_name"]); ?>.
        <?php
    }
    else {
        ?><br>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>Your Name: <input type="text" name="full_name" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn"></p>
        </form>
        <br>
        <?php
    }
?>
```